# What is the right way of using try and catch with JS?

Tags: javascript

My code structure on Node.js when a request is received is sliced to functions like this:

```
function first() {
 if (someTrue) 
  return second();
 if (!someTrue)
  return catched(); // handle the error back to client
}

function second() {
 // and so for and so on until it goes to finished(); function in case
 // that there no errors at all
}
```

Now sometimes there errors. You cannot avoid this. Maybe its related to using an undefined variable from user or something else.
I thought about wrapping each function's code into a `try and catch`, like this:

```
function first() {
 try {
  if (someTrue) 
   return second();
  if (!someTrue)
   return catched(); // handle the error back to client
 }
 catch(err) {
  return catched([err.name + ": " + err.message]);
 }

}
```

Is it okay?

Comment: Just to reply your statement (*You cannot avoid this*) that isn't true.

Comment: you code without errors at all?

Comment: @ele If that were the case, why would languages have features like `try`/`catch` in the first place?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question

Comment: @JamesThorpe the OP is talking about (*Maybe its related to using an undefined variable*), you cannot think that an undefined variable from a client should be catched, that's not true, not ok at all.  You can avoid that making validations.  The `try-catch` block exists to handle FATAL errors in your system.